# subquery not working in documentdb

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

My following query is working..

```
SELECT d.pub_user.userid FROM d where d.pri_data.user.email="xxx@yyy.zzz"
```

This gives me result as below..

```
[
  {
    "userid": "1e4491ef27097262"
  },.....
]
```

The following query is also working..

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.pub_user.userid  IN ("1e4491ef27097262")
```

But, when I try the following, it does not work..

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.pub_user.userid  IN (SELECT d.pub_user.userid FROM d where d.pri_data.user.email="xxx@yyy.zzz")
```

It gives an error.. `Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'SELECT'`

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078699/documentdb-sub-query).

Answer (score 4):

subquery is currently not supported. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078699/documentdb-sub-query#answer-39355495) answer, you can try to leverage a stored procedure.

When one start hitting joins or subquery is an early indicator that your data document structure is not optimal. I am however wondering why you cannot query by email without subquery in your final example. Like this

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.pri_data.user.email="xxx@yyy.zzz"
```

If this is not possible because these data are in separate documents perhaps email could be added to the docments.

Comment: starting with docdb.. can u please help with the stored procedure required in my case, tx..

Comment: @Arnab -Please don't ask additional questions in comments. And building a stored procedure is not in the scope of this question. Plenty of documentation on DocumentDB stored procedures.